# Emacs Syntax Table Modifications

Tags: syntax, syntax-table

I am looking to write my own major mode.

The programming language that I need to write it for has //... and /* ... */ style comments. I am having a very hard time getting the syntax tables working for both at the same time.

How would I get both of them at the same time?

Comment: Also, I am not looking to copy the syntax table from the c syntax table as it has LOTS of things that I don't want.

Comment: There is an example of the right values in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Descriptors.html

Comment: But that page of doc does not have both style comments at the same time as an example i can use

Comment: The question is unclear, and so risks being closed. "*I am having a very hard time...*" Specify just what your hard time is. Show some code. Describe just what you've tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: @Nick It does actually as `c-mode` supports both `// ...` and `/* ... */` comment styles.  See `cc-langs.el` for the source.